# Converting string to integer hex value "Strange" behaviour

Tags: java

I have noticed java will not allow me to store large numbers such as
2000000000, i.e 2 billion obviously to an integer type, but if I store the corresponding hex value i.e `int largeHex = 0x77359400`; this is fine,

So my program is going to need to increment up to 2^32, just over 4.2 billion, I tested out the hex key `0xffffffff` and it allows me to store as type int in this form,

My problem is I have to pull a HEX string from the program.

Example

```
sT = "ffffffff";

int hexSt = Integer.valueOf(sT, 16).intValue();
```

this only works for smaller integer values

I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ffffffff"
```

All I need to do is have this value in an integer variable such as

```
int largeHex = 0xffffffff
```

which works fine?

I'm using integers because my program will need to generate many values.

Comment: Why does `int j = 2000000000` not work? Two billion fits within 31 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems there is nothing to add to the answers, but it's worth it to clarify:

- It throws an exception on parsing, because `ffffffff` is too big for an integer. Consider `Integer.parseInt(""+Long.MAX_VALUE);`, without using hex representation. The same exception is thrown here.
- `int i = 0xffffffff;` sets `i` to `-1`.
- If you already decided to use longs instead of ints, note that `long l = 0xffffffff;` will set `l` to `-1` as well, since `0xffffffff` is treated as an int. The correct form is `long l = 0xffffffffL;`.

Comment: nothing to add to the answers? am i missing something?, i have no problem declaring 0xffffffff as an integer, and i can read the value back

Comment: sorry example       int test = 0xffffffff  System.out.println("test = "+Integer.toHexString(test));

Comment: so my question is if i can decalre an integer to that value, why if i have it in a string can i not assign an int to that value??

Comment: Because James Gosling wanted it :) You can write `int i = (int)Long.MAX_VALUE;` and it will be `-1`. I agree that it is weird, because compiler complains on `int i = 4294967295;` but doesn't complain on `int i = 0xffffffff;`. I think, basically this is because `0x...` is treated as a bit sequence and then is casted to the desired type.

Comment: ye im stumped, it sounds so simple what i need to do:|, there has to be a way,

Comment: haha, thanks for the answer, i have wasted a day messing aroung trying to get integers working, another thing i found although java will allow you to assign a hex number of 4.3billion to an int and printing this value is also fine, but when it comes to comparing or any arithmetic this does not work, its very misleading

Answer (score 7):

```
String hex = "FFFFFFFF"; // or whatever... maximum 8 hex-digits
int i = (int) Long.parseLong(hex, 16);
```

Gives you the result as a signed int ...

Answer (score 2):

How about using:

```
System.out.println(Long.valueOf("ffffffff", 16).longValue());
```

Which outputs:

```
4294967295
```

Comment: i need to convert from a hex string to an integer hex,not print it out, as i said i can assign an int as 0xffffffff and use it increment it read it back etc.. but say if i have a string "ffffffff" how can i assign it to a hex int like before w/o getting major erros

Comment: You have to use the "long" Java primitive type instead of the "int" one in order to be able to work with such a large value, i.e.:

<code>long value = Long.valueOf("ffffffff", 16).longValue();</code>

Answer (score 2):

The `int` data type, being signed will store values up to about 2^31, only half of what you need. However, you can use `long` which being 64 bits long will store values up to about 2^63.

Hopefully this will circumvent your entire issue with hex values =)

Comment: No i have had no problem storing integer values up2 2^32-1 aslong!! as there in hex,

Comment: You shoudn't need to use hex at all as long as you declare your variables as long. Simnply replace `int` with `long` in your code above.

Comment: yes, i am using longs now, the fact of the matter was that java allows signing of integer up2 4.3 billion alsong as its represented in hex, i though great ill use ints as it will save on disk space when writing these billions of keys out, but in the end behaviour just got to strange so i resorted to long

Comment: I think the naming of the data types is what is causing the confusion. Both int and long are Integer data types (along with byte and short), but they are different sized Integer types. If you look at how C++ defines them it may make more sense - a `long` in java is defined as `long int` in C++ just as you can have `short int` and `unsigned int` as well. All Integer types, but allowing the storage of a different range of values.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `BigInteger`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: I cannot as stated im generating 2^32 keys, i will have to write them to a file also no way can i use a big int

Comment: You can always write a <code>BigInteger</code> instance to a file as a <code>String</code>.

<pre><code>
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("ffffffff", 16);
String s = bi.toString();
Writer w = null;
try {
  w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename.txt"));
  w.write(s);
} finally {
  if (w != null) {
    w.close();
  }
}
</code></pre>

Answer (score 0):

int test = 0xFFFFFF;
int test2 = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(test), 16);

^---That works as expected... but:

int test = 0xFFFFFFFF;
int test2 = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(test), 16);

^--That throws a number format exception.

int test = 0xFFFFFFFF;
int test2 = (int)Long.parseLong(Integer.toHexString(test), 16);

^--That works fine.