# Java Color(int rgba) constructor and int overflow

Tags: java, colors, int, awt

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20boolean%29), this constructor exists:

```
public Color(int rgba,
         boolean hasalpha)
```

I'm failing to see how you could use this to create the equivalent of `Color(255,255,255,255)` (e.g. `0xFFFFFFFF`) given that java has no unsigned ints, however.

How do you use this constructor for a "big" color?

**EDIT**

Evidently the constructor can be used (surprise), but parsing an RGBa color string like this fails:

```
    int x = Integer.parseInt("0xFFFFFFFF", 16); // Number format error
    Color c = new Color(x, true);
```

The solution seems to be to use BigInteger to do the parsing. Sorry for the misdirected question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not misdirected, but you seems to have misunderstood Kon's answer:

You are right about Java's Integer being signed all the time, but this doesn't mean that there are less bits of information in that number.

When you create a Color:

```
new Color(255, 255, 255, 255)
```

it is the same as using:

```
new Color(0xFFFFFFFF, true)
```

or using:

```
new Color(0b11111111111111111111111111111111, true)
```

`0xFFFFFFFF` is in fact `-1`, but this doesn't mean that any of the bits change; It's only a question of representation. The `Color` just cuts out the necessary bits for each color component.

So you can, in fact, create your desired color using:

```
Color c = new Color(-1,true);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(c.getAlpha());
```

which yields:

```
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
255
```

Comment: Helpful, thanks. More of my confusion was coming from the behavior discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355619/converting-string-to-intger-hex-value-strange-behaviour).

Answer (score 2):

Go binary.

Color c = new Color(0b11111111111111111111111111111111, true);

As per the Java docs, "alpha component is in bits 24-31, the red component is in bits 16-23, the green component is in bits 8-15, and the blue component is in bits 0-7"

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFF is exactly the same number. And the binary representation only work for java 7 and up.

Comment: So? The docs explain the aRGB bit positions, so it's an easy way to do it and make it clear. Not worth a -1 because the answer is correct, I just used the literal definition of the Javadocs linked by OP to stress the point.

Comment: I misunderstood that you actually did comprehend the problem at hand, because in my eyes your answer did not reflect it. I'll be able to remove my downvote if you edit your answer to make that point more clear.

Comment: No worries, I didn't really provide an explanation so your concern is understandable. I added a blurb about how I got to my answer.